# Hyperv_fb not working

Tags: 14.04, hyper-v

I'm trying to run an Ubuntu VM on my windows 10 pc. 
The VM works fine but I want to run it on a full screen.

I followed some tutorials online and doing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1680x1050" in /etc/default/grub.
```

allows me to run fullscreen. But there is noticeable lag. 
So I enabled RemoteFX on hyper-v and the lag is gone, but hyperv_fb stops running so stuck with a fixed resolution (and the mouse is not being mapped from the main desktop)

When I disable **RemoteFX** the vm goes back to full screen mode.

So the question is why is **hyperv_fb** not working when I enable remoteFX? :(

Answer (score 0):

hyperv_fb is looking for the Hyper_V video driver.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/fbdev/hyperv_fb.c

When enabling RemoteFX, that driver is not loaded. As far as I know RemoteFX 3D accelerated adapters are not supported in Linux guests. I am still researching this, as it would be nice.